# asp.net 4.5.512 has not been registered on the web server

Tags: asp.net

ASP.NET 4.5.512 has not been registered on the web server. You need to manually configure your Web server.

Note: 
1) I ran `aspnet_regiis -i` at `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319`, now I'm getting 6 message boxes with same above error message
2) I tried turing on `IIS-ASPNET45` in `Turn Windows Features On/Off` under `Internet Information Services-> World Wide Web Services -> Application Development Features -> ASP.NET 4.5`.

Answer (score 12):

If you're running Visual Studio 2012, the following update may fix your problem.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3002339

Comment: This will work for VS 2012 and read this link may useful too: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_apps-insider_other-insiderplat_pc/aspnet-45256-has-not-been-registered-on-the-web/d43fe29b-3499-49d2-a6c6-cd0a3ecef2bc?auth=1